# Where do the system error reports go?

Tags: error-handling, apport, whoopsie

Every once in a while an error pops up, so there's this dialogue box which asks if one would like to inform Ubuntu about it. Upon confirming, where does this report go? Can it be followed up? If it is followed up, is there a fix that is provided later? Or is there some place where the solution is provided, which one can check and sort ot out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system which intercepts crashes right when they happen the first time is [**Apport**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport). When a crash happens, you will see something like this:

[image]

A report is written automaticaly in a file `*executable_path.uid*.crash` in the `/var/crash` directoty:

[image]

If you want to print one of these reports, you can run in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) next command:

```
lpr <executable_path.uid>.crash
```

More about: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport.

Comment: thanks a lot! one unrelated thing, though,which file browser are you using ?

Comment: @Projjol If you are referring at the above image, I used Gedit, not a file browser. I use [GNOME Commander](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-commander/).