# Ubuntu 18.04 reports "system program problem detected" approximately 1min after login

Tags: error-handling

The message offers cancel or report problem, is there a way to see what is reported?
I have looked for errors in dmesg but found none.
Is there any way to find what is creating this error ?
This was happening on both an amd and an intel based system but has disappeared from the Intel machine

Sort of fixed, until the next time

Comment: Don't you have the ["show details" button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318791/where-do-the-system-error-reports-go)?

Comment: There are only "Cancel" and "Report" buttons. Perhaps the question should be "Where is the Details Button"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do the system error reports go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318791/where-do-the-system-error-reports-go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared after the last but one system update. Just like the other machine